# how to create master page for already defined web forms in asp.net 2010 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have  login,register and welcome web forms in my project in this forms are designed and codded 
now i am going create a master page for this project

how can i create a master page for this 3 forms in web application.

i know only the creation of master page first and then select web form using master page this concept i clearly know.

but i want to create a master page for this already designed web forms...

how can i do this any one help me?....

you humble replies are welcomed............
thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Generally, I would just say that you [should learn ASP.NET documentation a bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX). As a web-developer you must know such basic things for sure!*

I won't describe how you create MasterPage -- you said you already know that.

But to move your existent pages to it, you should:

- add a reference to it in your page header:

  ```
  <%@ Page ... MasterPageFile="~/PathToThePage/YourMasterPage.master" ... %>
  ```
- then use asp:Content blocks to put your html of child page into the blocks defined in master page:

  ```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHeader" runat="Server">
      some parts of child page
  </asp:Content>
  ```

ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHeader" -- this is ContentPlaceHolder you define in your master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentHeader" runat="server">
    Some part which will be replaced with child page
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```